# How to fetch data received by ajax success function

Tags: php, ajax

In my program I used ajax to perform PHP code in another page...and I am receiving data performed by another page which is the URL of ajax perfectly,but I don't know how to access data from the received data in ajax.... 
code is given bellow...

**ajax code**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#search_text').keyup(function(){
            var txt = $(this).val();
            if(txt!=''){
                $.ajax({
                    url:"fetch.php",
                    method:"POST",
                    data:{search:txt},
                    datatype:"text",
                    success:function(data){
                        $('#result').html(data);
                    }
                });
            }
            else{
                $('#result').html('');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**php code on fetch.php**

```
<?php
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ajmal");
    $output = '';

    $sql = "SELECT 
    medicinName,pricerPerSheet,dealerID,availAbleAt,district,place FROM 
    medicinalinfo WHERE medicinName LIKE '%".$_POST["search"]."%'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {


        $output .= '<h4 align="center" class="h4_search">Search 
        Result</h4>';
        $output .= '<div class="row">';
        $output .= '<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-3 well">';
        $output .= '<div class="table-responsive">
                    <table id="getval" id="tbl" class="table table-bordered 
                    table-striped table-hover">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Medicin Name</th>
                        <th>Price Per Sheet</th>
                        <th>Availble At</th>
                        <th>District</th>
                        <th>Area</th>
                    </tr>';
        $output .= '</div>';
        $output .= '</div>';
        $output .= '</div>';
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $output .= '
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>'.$row['medicinName'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['pricerPerSheet'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['availAbleAt'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['district'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['place'].'</td>
                   </tr>
                </tbody>
            ';
       }
       $output.='</table>';

       $output.='<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"> 
       </script>';
       $output.='<script>

            var table = document.getElementById(\'getval\');

            for(var i=0; i<table.rows.length; i++){
                table.rows[i].onclick = function(){
                    alert(this.cells[0].innerHTML);
                    alert(this.cells[1].innerHTML);
                    alert(this.cells[2].innerHTML);
                    alert(this.cells[3].innerHTML);
                };
            }

        </script>
        ';
        echo $output;
      }
    else
    {
        echo '<h4 align="center" class="h4_search">Data Not Found</h4>';
    }
?>
```

Now I want to access specific data from the received **data** in success function of ajax code....say the **data** is receiving a table and I want to get  value of any cell of the selected row of the table.How to access the information that I want from **data**...

**all I have to do is in ajax code not in the ftch.php**

Comment: Please escape the user provided data - or rather, use prepared statements - before adding it to a sql query. Currently you are open to SQL injections, and that's very bad.

Comment: `I want to get the value of any cell of the selected row of the table`-> how's you are going to select a row of a table?

Comment: @AjmalHossain  don't add an event handler in the loop. single event handler will be fine.And do it seperatly from php

Comment: @AjmalHossain  did you checked my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***1.Please remove below part from `fetch.php`:-***

```
$output.='<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"> 
       </script>';
       $output.='<script>

            var table = document.getElementById(\'getval\');

            for(var i=0; i<table.rows.length; i++){
                table.rows[i].onclick = function(){
                    alert(this.cells[0].innerHTML);
                    alert(this.cells[1].innerHTML);
                    alert(this.cells[2].innerHTML);
                    alert(this.cells[3].innerHTML);
                };
            }

        </script>
        ';
```

***2.In the page where you have ajax code add this below given code:-***

```
$('#result').on('click','table tr',function(){
  var obj = $(this);
  var html = '';   
  obj.find('td').each(function(){
     html += $(this).html() +',';
  });
  alert($.trim(html));
});
```

***To assign values to separate variables:-***

```
$('#result').on('click','table tr',function(){
  var obj = $(this);
  var cell1_val =  obj.find('td').eq(0).html();
  var cell2_val =  obj.find('td').eq(1).html();
  var cell3_val =  obj.find('td').eq(2).html();
  var cell4_val =  obj.find('td').eq(3).html();
});
```

Comment: @AjmalHossain  glad to help you :):)